# Killing GUI background processes on logout

Tags: unity, gnome-session

I am logging into Ubuntu 16.04, and have written a startup application that runs redshift in the background:

`exec redshift`

To start this upon login, I added it under Ubuntu's Startup Applications.

After logging out, I can see the redshift process continuing to run under `ps`. A session is also visible for that user when running `loginctl`.

My questions are:
1) does there exist a way to have logout kill the background processes?
2) Is redshift ignoring a signal and thus not shutting down properly?